# Create mapping that works both with a motion and a count

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions, count

I'd like to have a mapping that separates words, like this:

```
noremap RJ :s/\>\s*\</\r/g<CR>=''
```

I can do `3RJ` with that.

I can also create opfunc, so I can do `RJ}`:

```
noremap RJ :set opfunc=splitline#splitline<CR>g@

function! splitline#splitline(type) range abort
    execute line("'[") . ',' . line("']") . 's/\>\s*\</\r/g'
    let @/ = @"
    normal =''
endfunction
```

But how do I combine those two approaches together?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you would have a separate mapping for an operator that would work on the current line and take a count to work on a set of lines. For example, you could have `RJ{motion}` to act on a motion or text object, and `RJJ` to act on the current line or on a set of lines if given a count.

Having said that, you *can* have your mapping behave differently and act on a set of lines (possibly only one) when given a count, and expect a motion when not given one.

All you have to do is make it an `<expr>` mapping and then check whether `v:count` is larger than 0 to implement the first case.

You could duplicate the logic of `:s/\>\s*\</\r/g` to implement the case where a count is given, but perhaps easier is to set `'opfunc'` unconditionally and then use `g@_` for the case where you want to consider only the current line, or "n" lines when given a count.

(See [`:help _`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#_) for more information on the `_` motion. The `_` motion is typically equivalent to the double letter commands, e.g. `yy` is the same as `y_`, `dd` same as `d_`, `cc` same as `c_` and so on. It's very useful to refer to the current line and work for "n" lines when given a count.)

Putting it all together:

```
function! splitline#setup_splitline()
    set opfunc=splitline#splitline
    if v:count > 0
        return 'g@' . v:count . '_'
    else
        return 'g@'
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> RJ splitline#setup_splitline()
```